# What does "Use" mean in Organization-Wide Defaults of Pricebook object?

Tags: pricebook, product, owd, sales, organization-wide

I was looking for OWD Settings for `Product2` object and found that OWD for `Product2` is managed by `Pricebook` object.

On checking the defaults in `Pricebook` object, it is set at `Use` unlike others which are `Private` or `Public Read-Only` for instance.
[image: Pricebook OWD]

Although, I have not had to grant access to `Pricebook` or `Product` object explicitly to any user so far, I am still curious to know what it means.

I have not been able to find any explanation on the [documentation regarding Pricebook Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=products_sharing.htm&type=5) either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is the snapshot of the access levels for Price book [image]

Please refer to [this link for more information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5)